# Strange latency discrepancy on simultaneous wired/wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have hooked up my laptop and tower to a switch with ethernet cables. Both are windows 10 running more or less the latest updates. I've manually configured each to the following settings:

```
Tower:
IP Address: 10.0.0.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Speed: 10 Mbps

Laptawp:
IP Address: 10.0.0.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Speed: 1 Gbps
```

I also have both of them connecting to a router downstairs using their on board wireless cards. The tower has address 192.168.0.7 and the laptop has address 192.168.0.10.

If I ping 192.168.0.10 from 192.168.0.7 and vice versa (the wireless network), I get reasonable latency, like under 2ms.

However if I ping 10.0.0.1 from 10.0.0.2 and vice versa, I get ridiculous latency, around the 2000ms mark. This baffles me. Surely a direct wired connection would be faster than a wireless connection which runs through a router located in another room?

Perhaps it's because the ethernet connection on the tower is quite old (10 Mbps). Is that why i'm getting these crazy latency stats on the wired network? (Even if it is an old ethernet card, i wouldn't expect the latency to be quite that high.) I note that I'm going to upgrade the ehternet card in the tower to gigabit internet soon, but I figure i'd ask this question here regardless just in case there's some sort of software problem which changing card wouldn't resolve.

Comment: A 10Mbps connection wouldn't cause that type of latency. What is the output of traceroute from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2, and what's your routing table look like? Are you sure the ethernet cable on the laptop is good? If you don't have a spare, swap the cable between the laptop and the lower then repeat test and look at link speeds.

Comment: Have you checked the cabling? Do you have another (wired) ethernet device to rule out either the Tower or the Laptop as the problem spot? One thing you could do is force the 10Mbps card (how old is it anyway?) to Full Duplex and see if this helps.

Comment: How old is the tower exactly? 10 Mbps only cards should have been gone decades ago and most of them wouldn't even fit on a Win10 system anymore; is this e.g. a 100 Mbps capable card that you manually configured to run at 10 Mbps? And either way, did you configure the other end to match the speed and duplex settings? (Or did you just mix up 10 and 100 Mbps in your post?)

Comment: the tower's ethernet is built into the motherboard. I can get the exact model deets later but i can say for now that the name "Realtek" keeps popping up on all the diagnostic info.

Comment: the speed being reported is 10mbps, which is indeed suspiciously low. The tower was built in 2008 (with various upgrades over the years), so I would expect at least 100mbps, but that doesn't seem  to be the case

Comment: Have you tried switching the cables?  You still need to provide specific hardware information to properly identify the source of your problem